# Enter a website, only the user (forgot password)

Tags: passwords

I have forgotten the password of a user on a page in my country, and the server gives an error when requesting the code to change the password... (Bad Request)

I want to know if there is a unique key that my username and that of my family will have that we are all waiting for...

Someone help me, I pay them for it (Paypal)

To access. Be able to enter my username

Comment: Sorry, there's nothing we can really do to help.  If you've lost your password and the server isn't able to help you recover, you're stuck.

Comment: Also, since this question isn't about programming, it's off topic for stack overflow.  Good luck!